# Debian error: ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"

Tags: linux, networking, debian, virtualbox, vb

Since today Debian gives an error: ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"

If I look up the interfaces file I see the following:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dchp

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dchp
```

I'm running Debian in a Virtual Box; eth0 is a NAT and eth1 is a host-only adapter
I also tried it with an ethernet cable plugged in, but that didn't make a change.

How can I get rid of this error?

Thank you in advance,

Remco

Comment: Can you put `strace -fv ifup eth0` to `pastebin.com` or a similar site?

Answer (score 12):

You'll probably kick yourself, but you've got the same typo on two lines. It should be `iface eth0 inet dhcp` not `dchp`.

`ifup` and `ifdown` will break if they can't parse the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with static ip configuration
In my case said
/etc/network/interfaces:2: misplaced option
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
lo que hice es que colocar ( # ) en las linea ( 2 )
example
1-- #auto lo
2-- #iface lo inet loopback

And raise the network again with the command
ifup eth0

I hope someone will use this reference on the line that poorly written